# Shall i add If Exists to my SQL Stored Procedure?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, sql-function

Afternoon All,

I have a button on a web page that when is clicked by the user inserts data into a table.  this button has a message box assigned to it, to let the user know the records have been saved and then redirects the user to the home page.    This in its current state works perfectly fine.

My problem is that I wish to find a solution to stop the user going back to the page where this button is located and inserting the data again.  I need to get round having duplicate records in the database table.

I’m presuming that from what I have read on the internet that I should be using the ‘IF EXISTS’ function within my stored procedure.  I’m not 100% sure how this will work with the current code that I have in my Stored Procedure?  I’m only want to check that these records are available and if not then to add add them or if they already exist then not to add these.

I just think that I have confused myself slightly with the amount of articles etc that I have read on the internet.

Here is my current stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GasNominationsRawData_Insert]

AS SET NOCOUNT ON;  

INSERT INTO dbo.GasRawData (timestamp,TagName,Value) 

    SELECT timestamp AS Interval, Left(Right(TagName,Len(TagName)-5),Len(TagName)-10) As TagName,
    CONVERT(decimal(10, 2), ROUND(value, 2)) As Value
    FROM 
       OPENQUERY(IHISTORIAN,'
        SET starttime =''yesterday +4h'', endtime =''today +6h'' 
        SELECT timestamp, tagname, value
        FROM ihRawData
        WHERE tagname = "UMIS.99FC9051.F_CV"
           OR tagname = "UMIS.99F851C.F_CV"
           OR tagname = "UMIS.35GTGAS.F_CV"
           OR tagname = "UMIS.99XXG546.F_CV"
        AND timestamp BETWEEN ''timestamp'' and ''timestamp'' 
        AND SamplingMode =Calculated
        AND CalculationMode =Average
        AND IntervalMilliseconds =1h
        ORDER BY tagname, timestamp
        ')
```

Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Regards Betty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One very simple way of preventing duplicates is to add a `UNIQUE INDEX` on the field(s) you want to keep distinctive.

`CREATE UNIQUE INDEX ix_MyIndexName ON Table(Field1, Field2, Field3)`

This will throw an error if you try to insert a duplicate value for the fields listed.

Alternatively, you can add the option `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON` to the above to continue if a duplicate value is attempted to be inserted.  A warning will be generated but it won't cause the query to fail.

This has minimal overhead and won't require you to do any maintenance work.

Comment: Afternoon JNK,  Creating a UNIQUE INDEX I think sounds good.  However I would just like to check that it would work against some sample records. My table columns in the DB are ‘timestamp’, ‘tagname’, &’Value’. Sample records (for two tags only) in the DB would look like the following: (Timestamp, tagname, Value) 27/10/2011 05:00 99F851C 0.03, 27/10/2011 06:00 99F851C 0.03, 27/10/2011 05:00 99FC9051 14.62, 27/10/2011 06:00 99FC9051 13.66. Please see next part of comments...

Comment: Essentially there will be duplicate ‘timestamp’  as my query pulls back an hourly interval for each tag from yesterday 05:00am to the current date 06:00am. So I need to make sure that the duplicates are not that of the individual ‘timestamp’ + ’tagname’.   Would CREATE UNIQUE INDEX DupRecords ON GasRawData (Timestamp, tagname) work?

Comment: Hi JNK,  Yeah, creating the index did work as such.  However i now have an exception that i need to resolve and im not so sure how to do this. "Cannot insert duplicate key row in object 'dbo.GasRawData' with unique index 'DupRecords'.
The statement has been terminated."  This refers to the dbcommand.ExecutedNonQuery() line on the vb page?   I will try and post the code up for the button it is used within if you are able to help?

Comment: You need to use the `IGNORE_DUP_KEY = ON` that I mentioned, or handle errors.

Comment: Protected Sub btnAddRawData_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnAddRawData.Click
        Using dbconnection As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("dbconnection"))
            dbconnection.Open()
  Using dbcommand As SqlCommand = dbconnection.CreateCommand
              With dbcommand
                .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                .CommandText = "GasNominationsRawData_Insert"
                dbcommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
                End With
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
End Class

Comment: @Betty - use the option I mentioned.  If you have an issue with the application then open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

When you say "duplicate", do you mean a duplicate of the `TagName`?  If so, the easiest solution would be to use a unique constraint on that field in the table.  Or you could also use an `AFTER INSERT` trigger to check if that `TagName` already exists (maybe with the combination of `VALUE`?), and if so then `ROLLBACK` the transaction.

Comment: The "Duplicate" records in question are the records for the'timestamp' & 'tagname'. Each of the specified 'tagnames' above have data for hourly intervals. The query above pulls back 26 hourly intervals for each tagname that start off from 05:00am of the previous day to 06:00am of the current date?

Answer (score 0):

I would do an If EXISTS

Basically just do

```
IF EXISTS( select * from wherever where something = something )
BEGIN
-- Return an error here
Return 0
END
ELSE
BEGIN
 -- Insert Code Goes Here
Return 1
END
```

Then when you exec your SP if it returns 0 you know it errored and you can display a message to your user about inserting duplicate data. This approach will mean that you can detect the result of the query and if it has not inserted due to duplicates you can display an appropriate message, it will also give you confirmation that the record has inserted.